# How do I amend a Symfony2 form based on field value selected by the user?

Tags: forms, symfony, event-listener

I have a *Blog* type, and I want certain fields to be added to the form only if the user makes a certain selection in the *select* field. I have heard of *EventListener*, but I don't think there is a FormEvent I can subscribe to so the listener can actually track the select event.

How can I achieve this?

This is my *BlogType*:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener\AddAuthorFieldSubscriber;

class BlogType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('blog')
            ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'BloggerBlogBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
            )
            ->add('onlyifdefaultcategory')
        );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'blogger_blogbundle_blogtype';
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm having the same problem, fill a form after the user makes a certain selection in the select field.

Answer (score 2):

You're right when you say you have to use event listener to achieve this. There is a very good article in Symfony cookbook : [Here is the Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data).

You have to check the part "Customizing your Form based on the underlying Data".

If you need more information, tell us, but I think first example is exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I think its possible only using JavaScript. You can create custom *Type* and declare widget for this *Type* with JS, which makes its possible.

For building form, here is example with listeners.
Check this: [symfony manual](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)